# Compare the slopes of categorical data

Tags: regression, confidence-interval, application

Hello I want to compare the slopes of the linear regression lines for the following distributions of sales figures over the years 2009 to 2017.

[image]

I want to compare the slopes of the regression lines - examine if they differ significantly -

Approach: I draw additional confidence intervals for each regression line. If the slopes differ and the confidence intervals do not overlap for the given period, I know that the slopes are different.
Is that an appropriate approach? If not, what can I do?

Appreciate any help!!

Answer (score 1):

Remember you are estimating the slopes.  As you state it, the question is not "is the blue line statistically significantly above the other lines", but, "are the slopes really different"?

The first question is really about the significance of the intercept and/or dummy variables.

Look at the t-stats and values for the three slopes.  Roughly speaking, the problem you are asking is not a lot different than this one:

"if I measure the average height of 30 students in three different classrooms, is one of the rooms taller than the others with statistical significance?"

But, you are substituting "slope of regression line" in place of "height"

Comment: Thanks for your answer but how can I acieve that? Is it appropriate to draw confidence intervals around the linear regression lines and simply compare the slopes as well as the confidence intervals? If the slopes differ and the confidence intervals do not overlap, the slopes differ significantly?

Comment: I think the OP wants to test the slopes and not the dummy coefficients. In that case, it a test between a three slopes model vs. one common slope which can be done with a score test or LRT test as in my reply -- not the three wald tests of the coefficients.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you please further explain how I can use the t stats and the slope to achieve the desired result... do I have to compute a t test? If so how can I do that?

Comment: If you want to know if the slopes are statistically different, use the t-stats from the regression and apply the usual t-test for two populations with estimated means/parameters.  See:  http://onlinestatbook.com/2/tests_of_means/difference_means.html

Answer (score 1):

You can drop the three variables series into one regression and estimate:

1. A linear model with category dummies and a common slope for time. E.g., `lm(sales ~ category + time)` in R.
2. A linear model with category dummies and slope with dummy interaction. E.g., `lm(sales ~ category * time)` in R.

Then test the two models against each other with a likelihood ratio test using e.g., `anova` in R. See `help("anova")` for details.

You may want to account for the heterogeneity between the category which the above approach does not.